# Knockout.js: Bind visibility to validationMessage

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I am newbie in Knockout.js . I successfully could bind `validaionMessage` to `<p>` elements. All those `<p>` elements are placed inside a `div` and that `div` has special styling for errors. Now, I'd like to show `div` only when there are some `validationMessage` available. 
How can I do it?

```
<div class="error-container" >
     <p data-bind="validationMessage: age"></p>
     <p data-bind="validationMessage: sex"></p>
     <p data-bind="validationMessage: name"></p>
</div>
```

PS: I am using version `1.3.0rc` .

Comment: try this css <!-- ko if css: validationMessage -->:

Comment: @HemaNandagopal I get `Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: validationMessage is not defined ` error

Comment: Have you binded it in the model? ko.applyBindings({
    validationMessage: ko.observable(false)
});  try this <div data-bind="if: validationMessage ">

Answer (score 0):

In KnockoutJS you could do something like this

```
<!-- ko if: validationMessage -->
<div class="error-container" >
     <p data-bind="validationMessage: age"></p>
     <p data-bind="validationMessage: sex"></p>
     <p data-bind="validationMessage: name"></p>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

If the parametter passed to "ko if" is true, everything inside will be rendered in the view.
The thing is that if I don't know the rest of your code I can't tell what parameter you should pass to the "ko if", but this will give you an idea of how you can achieve what you want.

Comment: I get error `Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: validationMessage is not defined;`

Comment: The thing is I don't know what I should feed in to `ko if`

Comment: What you need is a boolean kind of counter that checks if you have an error or not.
Could you provide a basic demo based on your code so I can check?

Comment: I appreciate your help. Unfortunately, the legacy code I am struggling with contains bunch of libraries written on top of Knockout.

Comment: No problem. I know that maybe you've already check the official documentation but just in case you didn't, take a look at it:
Http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Maybe you can create a boolean observable that checks if there's an error or not.
Without a working snippet I do not think I could help you more.
Sorry

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="error-container"  data-bind="if: validationMessage" >
     <p data-bind="validationMessage: age"></p>
     <p data-bind="validationMessage: sex"></p>
     <p data-bind="validationMessage: name"></p>
</div>
```

Try this,